# set `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True` or not?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using pytorch and I wonder if I should use `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True`. I find on google that I should use it when computation graph does not change. What is computation graph in pytorch?

Comment: check out [these](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-does-torch-backends-cudnn-benchmark-do/5936) answers

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If your model does not change and your input sizes remain the same - then you may benefit from setting `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True`.
However, if your model changes: for instance, if you have layers that are only "activated" when certain conditions are met, or you have layers inside a loop that can be iterated a different number of times, then setting `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True` might stall your execution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If the model is a multi-task model. i.e., lower layers are shared and some higher layers are not. In this case, does the computation graph change?

Comment: I assume that using a dropout layer changes the model, right?

Comment: Another example is if you have variable batch sizes during inference. CUDNN will re-optimize for each new batch size it sees, which isn't worth it.